# Android twitter send direct message

Tags: android, twitter

I have integrated twitter with my application. Twitter posting is working fine. Now I am trying to send a direct message to one of follower but it showing **IlligalStateException:Authentication credentials are missing ensureAuthenticationEnabled.**

Here is my code to send direct message:

```
//SEND DIRECT MESSAGE TO TWITTER FRIENDS WALL
public static void sendDirectMessageToFriend(String friendId,String messsage){
    Twitter sender =new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    try {
        DirectMessage message = sender.sendDirectMessage(friendId, messsage);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println("Sent: " message.getText() + " to @" + message.getRecipientScreenName());
}
```

Comment: Am also facing same issue any idea of share ..........

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the error message:

> Authentication credentials are missing.

According to twitter4j's code example page:

To run the example codes, you need to have OAuth credentials configured in twitter4j.properties. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for instructions on how to do that..

You must be logged in to send direct messages on Twitter.  You need to configure your authentication credentials by one of the three methods given on the Twitter4J Configuration page before the code example will work. Try authenticating the user using a twitter4j.properties file, a ConfigurationBuilder, system properties or environment variables.